# Why the first and last image start to resize when resize the browser

Tags: html, css

Why the first and last image start to resize when resize the browser, Any clue about the problem. I want that image have the same size always.

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.contenedor{
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    background: green;
    justify-content: space-around;
     
}


.imagen{
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: contain;  
    background: red;

}
```

```html
    <div class="contenedor">
    <img class="imagen" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-m/1280/1b/39/85/d3/exterior.jpg" alt="" >
    <img class="imagen" src="https://a9u8z5j7.rocketcdn.me/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/playa_flaminio_paola_sanchez-1024x768.jpg" alt="" >
    <img class="imagen" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/gn16-yuplondev/1556914625569-1.jpg" alt="" >
    </div>
```

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: All three images resize at some point – what do you want them to do when they no longer fit on the screen?

Comment: I want all three images to start the resize at the same time.

But the following happens, image three starts the resize, then image one and finally image two.